# Trying to get a single node with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get a single node after I locate the htmlnode with a specific tag. 
But what I get back is an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Now here is the code:

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
// Creates an HtmlDocument object from an URL
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load(url);
// Targets a specific node
// If there is no node with that Id, someNode will be null
HtmlNode someNode = document.GetElementbyId("<li name=\"XU\">");
var parseString = someNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='lp']");
```

My purpose is to get all the nodes within the XU li tag. I know the name of the classes.

Also just to note that when I'm replacing the last code line with a

```
var parseString = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='long-position']");
```

then the tag argument within the SelectSingleNode is working fine.

Comment: `Any advice` on **which problem**? If it is working with `//span[@class='long-position']` then use it.

Comment: If you need a real answer for your question, you should post your html  code. This way I can tell you how to get the right parts out of it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code...

```
HtmlNode someNode = document.GetElementbyId("<li name=\"XU\">");
```

... probably returns null... then calling:

```
var parseString = someNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='lp']");
```

... throws that exception because someNode is null.

Try this:

```
HtmlNode someNode = document.GetElementbyId("XU");

if (someNode != null)
{
    var parseString = someNode.SelectSingleNode("/span[@class='lp']");
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlNode someNode = document.SelectSingleNode("//li[@name='XU']").SelectSingleNode("/span[@class='lp']");
```